# Run python crawler (Selenium Chrome) from PHP

Tags: python, php, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I have this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://python.org")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```

When called from shell it returns the title of python.org.

But when i call it from PHP

```
$result = exec("/usr/bin/python3 " . app_path() . "/webCrawler/test.py 2>&1", $return, $code);
print_r($result);
print_r($code);
print_r($return);
```

It returns below error, i have looked everywhere and nothing works so far, any idea what is going on.?

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(chrome not reachable)
(The process started from chrome location /snap/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

I have tried to change the chromedriver
I have tried to add some more debuging to the script with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out, the snap version that selenium was runing when called from php was not the same as the one php was using, or maybe in the wrong path, so i just added the path to snap chromedriver in selenium and that worked.